# PHP PDO and access database double result for single record

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

I have an ms access 2010 database with extension `*.accdb` and I manage to connect to the database using PDO and ODBC driver.

I tried to delete either the `*.mdb` or `*.accdb` and get an error, I don't know why it needs both the extensions.

This is the POC:

```
<?php
$dbName = 'here be path';
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) as MaxID from tbl";
$result = $db->query($sql);

foreach($result as $r) {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

The strange thing is the obtained result:

```
array (size=2)
  'MaxID' => string '21411' (length=5)
  0 => string '21411' (length=5)
```

Why do I get 2 entry for one expected result?
How can I obtain only this:

```
    array (size=1)
  'MaxID' => string '21411' (length=5)
```

The second thing is how can I optimize the PDO to get only one result without foreach?

Comment: that's normal. you didn't tell PHP what kind of result array/object to fetch, so it gave you the default: dual-keyed string and integer. It's not a "duplicate result", it's just pdo trying to be helpful

Comment: How can i fix that? Can you give me a hint please. Thank you.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: its returning an array indexed by number and name both. Decide which you want and just use that one, like `echo $arr[0];` or `echo $arr['name'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get doubled results, because default fetch style is set to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`:

> (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed
>   column number as returned in your result set

So you can call items in the array with the index number or the actual key name.

```
$result[0] or $result['MaxID'] will return the same result.
```

If you don't want duplicates change your style e.g. to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $r) {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

More about fetch styles you can find in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: You beat me to it. this is the answer.

Comment: "SELECT MAX(ID) as MaxID from tbl" this is fetching all the ids and returning the max(id)?

Comment: @Starlays Sorry, I don't looked at whole query, ma bad. MAX(ID) return only one result so `LIMIT` is bad idea here.